# Why does my try/catch block not work when triggering a Jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code, where I trigger a pipeline job in a multi-branch pipeline setup. All the variables are defined.

```
    // *** This is NOT the issue! ***
    // Force a scan to the mulit-branch pipeline.
    build job: buildJobForFeatureBranch,
          wait: false
    sleep(10)

    // *** This is the issue! ***
    // We intentionally do this twice. If it's a newly scanned
    // feature branch, the first call to it will fail because
    // of a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline bug where not all the
    // parameters are setup up yet.
    try {
      build job: cm.ftBuildJob,
            parameters: [
              string(name: "VERSION_PASSEDIN", value: srcBranch),
              string(name: "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS", value: "true"),
              string(name: "DEBUG_LEVEL", value: "0")
            ],
            wait: true
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      build job: cm.ftBuildJob,
            parameters: [
              string(name: "VERSION_PASSEDIN", value: srcBranch),
              string(name: "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS", value: "true"),
              string(name: "DEBUG_LEVEL", value: "0")
            ],
            wait: true
    }
```

However, my pipeline just fails after the first call to the `build job` plugin. What's the correct way to do this? TIA.

Comment: i believe `build job: ...` is not throwing exception. even if job has status `failed` the job been executed and completed.

Comment: @daggett is likely correct, but logs would help confirm.

Comment: @daggett that actually makes sense. So how do I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/ ... `use the "result" property of the return value as needed` - just a guess according to this: `def buildResult = build job` and then `assert buildResult.result == ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a boolean parameter called `propagate` and as stipulated in [Build Step Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/), the default state is `disabled(false)`.

> ```
> try {
>  build job: cm.ftBuildJob,
>        parameters: [
>          string(name: "VERSION_PASSEDIN", value: srcBranch),
>          string(name: "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS", value: "true"),
>          string(name: "DEBUG_LEVEL", value: "0")
>        ],
>        wait: true,
>        propagate : true //Adding this line should do the job
> }
> ```

Keep me updated on your result

Comment: I don't get it. The `build job: cm.ftBuildJob ` is inside the `try{}` block. That's the one I'm having issues with. I edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you provide the log of your error ?

Comment: It's just a normal Jenkins job failure.

Comment: OK I found why it doesn't catch I will edit my answer